# How to enable TUN on Debian VPS?

Tags: debian, vps, openvpn, tun

I have a VPS with Debian7

Need to setup OpenVPN on it

So I had installed and configured OpenVPN but now um stuck with TUN error.

`lsmod | grep tun` - returns empty, so I need to load tun module to kernel.

`modprobe tun` - returns this

> modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:514 lookup_builtin_file() could
>   not open builtin file
>   '/lib/modules/2.6.32-042stab127.2/modules.builtin.bin' modprobe:
>   FATAL: Module tun not found in directory
>   /lib/modules/2.6.32-042stab127.2

Answer (score -1):

Tun is frequently built-in the kernel. You're using a very outdated kernel (2.6.32), [released in December 2009](https://kernelnewbies.org/LinuxVersions). Your kernel, however, was patched for Meltdown and Spectre this year, but remains mostly outdated. Also, it's important to notice that Debian 7 was shipped with kernel 3.2.

Searching for it ("2.6.32-042stab127.2"), I found it's a kernel [commonly used with OpenVZ or Virtuozzo](https://virtuozzosupport.force.com/s/article/000017420), a software platform which provides "containerized" VPS. Those VPS are much more limited than fully virtualized VPS, as they share the kernel with the host machine.

So, your VPS is probably the problem. A containerized VPS cannot interfere with the running kernel, that's a built-in limitation for security and design purposes in containerized servers. And even if you could, you'd be running a version different than the Debian 7 packages expect.

I recommend switching to a fully virtualized VPS, look for words like "KVM", "Qemu" or "Xen" in the description of the vendor. KVM, Qemu and Xen are virtualization platforms that fully isolate the virtualized machine, including the kernel. So you would be able to make any modifications to the kernel you want.

Comment: Btw, the support tell me that thay are turn on TUN/TAP interfaces on my VPS and i need to check it. I had reinstall openvpn, restart VPS but no changes.